# Local Environment working, when pushed up to amplify Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Describe the bug:
I have set up an app with CI/CD pipeline with GitHub. I used create react app and various packages. I connected a backend environment that has provisioned graphql and cognito components.

I have different branches connected to different custom domains dev/qa/prod, and have been developing and deploying successfully to the dev branch with little to no issues.

After doing some work I committed the code pushed it up which started the build in amplify.

Locally "npm start running on local host", the app runs with no errors or warnings.
When I look at the deployed app there is a blank screen with this error

[image]

I've Tried So Far:

I have worked my way back commenting out components and uninstalling packages to try to nail down a particular spot where I could have introduced something. I ended up just importing App.js with
just a div with Hello in it and it still breaks after being deployed.

The initial error pointed to react-image-gallery (as seen in the picture I'm sharing), so I uninstalled that and got rid of the component but then the error just keeps going down the tree to another component, then another component....

The stack overflow posts about this particular error point to circular dependency issues or importing exporting things incorrectly. Why isn't this showing up locally then? I still took this advice and scoured my code to see if somewhere in my work I introduced something.

Expected behavior
Webb App is working in the local environment, after its built and deployed it is not working.

Reproduction steps
Travel to https://dev.jacobwazydragcourse.click/ open up console

App Id
d2nnfn8ylufs60

Region
us-east-2

Answer (score 0):

Also have this issue with React 17.0.2, Apache2 server, Ubuntu 20.x.  Works great locally, will not work on server.  Tried earlier versions of the library.  Changed all components in tree from Components to functional components.  Still have the issue.

Moving on to another way to get this effect in a page, but with components that work.